# How to implement wizard control in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, containers

In VB6 I have been using pictureboxes as containers a lot.
For example I put 5 pictureboxes onto a form, and as soon as the user clicked the "Next" button, I brought the next picturebox into the foreground.
This has been extremely convenient.

Now I am fighting with doing something similar in VB.NET.
My attempts were not really successful. A picturebox does not really hold my controls, they seem to jump out now and then, and I can not really make out on which picturebox a control is currently located since the picturebox is not opaque as in VB6.

Can somebody please tell me how to do this in a good way in VB.NET?

Comment: can you show us a screenshot of what the vb6 app looks like ?

Comment: A picture box should not hold controls in vb6 or .net. can you show us a screenshot of what the vb6 app looks like ? A panel should hold other controls. The screenshot you posted looks like its working properly I don't understand what 'BUGS' your talking about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e63s4df3.aspx) control

Comment: For me this just doesn't work without giving me headaches. I put two of them onto a form, and they have serious graphical bugs making it nearly impossible to really maintain them in the IDE.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing -- but I'm quite sure the Panel control is intended *exactly* for what you describe.

Comment: After looking at your screenshot, you may have one panel within the other.  If it becomes too difficult, either add/remove controls to the panel as needed, or put them side by side in the IDE, and move them to their appropriate locations in the Load event of your form.

Comment: They are not within each other. I will follow your advice of having them besides each other during design time and moving them over each other during Form_Load. Thank you!

Comment: You could also set a border on the panels, then set BorderStyle to None in the form load event, similarly change the BackColor, anything that helps distinguish them in the designer.

Comment: > they have serious graphical bugs ... Orly? Serious graphical bugs that were not fixed for 10 years?

Comment: Sorry, I need to ask again. Please take a look at the Thunderbird settings window: http://s15.postimage.org/g66qkdx23/thunderbird2.jpg How should I maintain this in the IDE? When I use panel and stuff them over each over (I have around 10 panels), they jump into each other. How do you others do this? In my desperation I am currently using a TabControl to host my controls. This way I do not have the jump-from-one-panel-to-the-other problem, but I feel not confident about this way of abusing the TabControl, and I haven't found out yet how to parent the controls to a picturebox when showing them.

Comment: You could consider creating a UserControl for each panel, that way you position your user controls 'carefully' once only, then you can edit each UserControl separately in its own designer.  You would have some work exposing each control value outside the UserControl, but that's just a tradeoff I suppose

Answer (score 0):

For your issues with panels that you posted a screenshot for.  Your panel is within another container, that's why it's displaying strangely.  Try clicking the panel and cutting it (ctrl-x) then clicking the form header, and pasting it (ctrl-p).  That will ensure it isn't within another control as sometimes that can happen in a way that isn't exactly obvious (like how you can see the control borders in your screenshot).